# jquery not function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used below code to toggle class for div.

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  
   <div class="members-section " id="as-member"><img 
    src="img/test1.jpg" alt="">
    <span>Join as a new member</span>
  </div>
   <div class="members-section " id="as-student"><img 
    src="img/test2.jpg" alt=""> 
    <span>Join as a student</span>
  </div>
  <div class="members-section "><img src="img/test3,jpg" alt="">
   <span>Upgrade my membership</span>
 </div>
 <div class="members-section test-member">
  <h5>Teest...</h5>
   <ul class="member-options">
    <li><span>Discounts</span></li>
    <li><span>Institute access</span></li>
    <li><span>Library access</span></li>
    <li><span>Market events</span></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<script>        
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#as-member').click(function(e){
        $('.members-section').not($(this)).toggleClass('unselected');
    });         
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code toggle the unselected class to all other div except current clicked element.

So I want the div also should not toggle which is containing the class **"test-member"**

Can this be achieved please? Anyone look into this and update me your thoughts Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an additional [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method that's it. Also, you don't need to wrap `this` to use with [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method since it accepts a DOM element object as an argument.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#as-member').click(function(e){
    $('.members-section').not(this).not('.test-member').toggleClass('unselected');
    // here -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------
  });         
});
```

---

Or you can add pseudo-class selector [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with the main selector.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#as-member').click(function(e){
    $('.members-section:not(.test-member)').not(this).toggleClass('unselected');
    // here -----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------------
  });         
});
```

Comment: @jafarpinjar : both will work.... on the first one I forgot to add a dot before class selector... updated now...